# error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized

Tags: mikeio

I am trying to install MIKEIO 1D to post-process .res1d files, but I keep getting the following error when I do `pip install mikeio1d`

```
Installing collected packages: pycparser, pythonnet, mikeio1d
  Running setup.py install for pythonnet ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for pythonnet did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
         or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
         or: setup.py --help-commands
         or: setup.py cmd --help
     
      error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pythonnet

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

How can I bypass this error?

Answer (score 0):

Pythonnet is not supported on Python 3.9, you can try the alpha release:

```
pip install pythonnet==3.0.0a2
```